# A temporate object as an argument is created after or before the call stack[/function frame]?

Tags: c++

Please see the example below first:

```
    struct myClass(){ 
        int x;
        myclass(int y){ x=y;} 
    };

    function(myClass object){};

    int main(){

    function( myClass(5) ); //function frame or temporary object is created first?
    }
```

If an argument that is NOT an already-defined object (meaning a temporate object) is passed to a function 
, then will the object be created before or after the creation of the function frame?

, and will a function frame contains the object too or the object is created somewhere else? Please help :)

Comment: Parameters are created in the context of the calling function.

Comment: Why do you wonder? What is your underlying problem or assignment/exercise?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm currently learning about how things are stored in the memory :)

Comment: @Rango you probably need to inspect the assembly.  As long as the compiler follows the Standard there is room for optimisations which would make any answer not useful to your situation.  Note that the Standard does not define / use "a stack frame".

Comment: @RichardCritten Oh. it's very painful to know that.

Comment: Such is life ... modern compiler optimizes all your code out and returns 0 from main.

Comment: Have a read of [Built-in function call operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_function_call_operator) and note that _"...The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs in the context of the caller, which means, for example, that if constructor of a parameter throws an exception, the exception handlers defined within the function [being called], even as a function-try block, are not considered...."_

Comment: @Rango Is it painful? Would you rather end up with slow and inefficient programs? BTW, you can do that. If you disable optimizations, your compiler will likely put everything on the stack.

Comment: @RichardCritten thank a lot, it seems like it's exactly what i'm looking for!

Comment: If not a secret, what you are actually studying? Is this for some essay in compilers? Certain books about system programming might be of help

Comment: no, it's not anything about university or any test. I'm learning all by myself. I try to learn C++ to run Unreal Engine 5, wanna be a game designer/programmer. I think memory is important later on so spend sometime on it. thanks for asking @Swift-FridayPie